# Can we use ThreeJs Helpers with InstancedMeshes?

Tags: three.js, mesh, react-three-fiber, geometry-instancing

I am newbie to Threejs and I am trying to use [axesHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/AxesHelper) to visualise the three axis of all the objects in a scene. Earlier I was using simple [Meshes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh) and all the helpers were working fine. Recently I've moved few objects to [Instanced Meshes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh) and the helpers have stopped working for them. I have confirmed this by trying with two helpers.(arrow and axes helper)

I am using [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber) to write for writing my threejs in JSX style.
Here is the code which used to work for me.

```
<mesh
      position={[geometry.position.x, geometry.position.y, geometry.position.z]}
      rotation={angle}
      geometry={geometry}>
      <meshLambertMaterial color={'red'} />
      <axesHelper />
</mesh>
```

Here is the new one which doesn't work.

```
<instancedMesh
      ref={ref}
      args={[(null as unknown) as BufferGeometry, (null as unknown) as Material, objects.length]}>
      <coneBufferGeometry args={[0.1, 0.1]}>
        <instancedBufferAttribute attachObject={['attributes', 'color']} args={[colorArray, 3]}/>
      </coneBufferGeometry>
      <meshLambertMaterial vertexColors />
      <axesHelper />
</instancedMesh>
```

So now I wanted to confirm if we can use these helpers for instanced meshes or not? I tried looking into three's documentation but was not able to find any answer related to this question.
I am on Threejs r127.

Answer (score 2):

As an option, you can decompose the matrices of instances and pass these values in attributes for `InstancedBufferGeometry`, based on geometry of `AxesHelper`.

It's just an example, not the ultimate solution.

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
console.clear();

import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 8, 13);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1));

let cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(0.5, 1, 2, 8);
let cylMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: "red", roughness: 0.25, metalness: 0.75,  polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: 1});
let cylinder = new THREE.InstancedMesh(cylGeom, cylMat, 100);
let dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
let mat4 = new THREE.Matrix4();
let counter = 0;
let pos = [];
let rot = [];
let scl = [];
for(let z = 0; z < 10; z++){
  for(let x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    dummy.position.set(-4.5 + x, 0, -4.5 + z).multiplyScalar(4);
    dummy.rotation.set(
      Math.random() * Math.PI * 2,
      Math.random() * Math.PI * 2,
      Math.random() * Math.PI * 2
    );
    dummy.updateMatrix();
    cylinder.setMatrixAt(counter, dummy.matrix);
    pos.push(dummy.position.x, dummy.position.y, dummy.position.z);
    rot.push(dummy.quaternion.x, dummy.quaternion.y, dummy.quaternion.z, dummy.quaternion.w);
    scl.push(dummy.scale.x, dummy.scale.y, dummy.scale.z);
    counter++;
  }
}
cylinder.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
console.log(cylinder);
scene.add(cylinder);

let axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(2);
console.log(axesHelper);
let lineGeom = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(axesHelper.geometry);
lineGeom.instanceCount = Infinity;
lineGeom.setAttribute("instT", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(pos), 3));
lineGeom.setAttribute("instR", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(rot), 4));
lineGeom.setAttribute("instS", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(scl), 3));
let lineMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: true,
  onBeforeCompile: shader => {
    shader.vertexShader = `
    attribute vec3 instT;
    attribute vec4 instR;
    attribute vec3 instS;
    
    // http://barradeau.com/blog/?p=1109
    vec3 trs( inout vec3 position, vec3 T, vec4 R, vec3 S ) {
        position *= S;
        position += 2.0 * cross( R.xyz, cross( R.xyz, position ) + R.w * position );
        position += T;
        return position;
    }
    ${shader.vertexShader}
`.replace(
      `#include <begin_vertex>`,
      `#include <begin_vertex>
      transformed = trs(transformed, instT, instR, instS);
`
    );
    console.log(shader.vertexShader);
  }
});
let lines = new THREE.LineSegments(lineGeom, lineMat);
scene.add(lines);

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

let clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
  let t = clock.getDelta();
  
  for(let i = 0; i < counter; i++){
    cylinder.getMatrixAt(i, mat4);
    mat4.decompose(dummy.position, dummy.quaternion, dummy.scale);
    dummy.rotation.x += t;
    dummy.rotation.z += t*.5;
    dummy.updateMatrix();
    cylinder.setMatrixAt(i, dummy.matrix);
    cylinder.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
    linesTRS(i, dummy);
  }
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})

function linesTRS(index, o){
  lineGeom.attributes.instT.setXYZ(index, o.position.x, o.position.y, o.position.z);
  lineGeom.attributes.instT.needsUpdate = true;
  lineGeom.attributes.instR.setXYZW(index, o.quaternion.x, o.quaternion.y, o.quaternion.z, o.quaternion.w);
  lineGeom.attributes.instR.needsUpdate = true;
  lineGeom.attributes.instS.setXYZ(index, o.scale.x, o.scale.y, o.scale.z);
  lineGeom.attributes.instS.needsUpdate = true;
}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight );

}
</script>
```